# I need to search a string for patterns from a list

Tags: python, string, list, search

Basically I have a list and I want to search a string for any pattern within it that also follows the list.

```
    KB1 = ["q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p"]

    Example = ("yada yada qwe tYu IoP weR")
```

and for every time it finds qwe ,tYu ,IoP and weR I just need it to add one to a variable, and as shown above needs to also find them regardless of capitalization.

```
    TimesPatternsAppear = 0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could concatenate the individual letters from the list to a string and then simply use the `in` or `find` operators to see if one string is found inside the other (as is done [here](https://www.afternerd.com/blog/python-string-contains/)). And if you apply the `.lower()` method to both strings (or, alternatively, `.upper()`, but it must be the same for both strings), it will be case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
KB1 = ["q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p"]
Example = "yada yada qwe tYu IoP weR"

string_as_a_list = Example.split(" ")
TimesPatternsAppear=0
for eachWord in string_as_a_list:
    eachWord = eachWord.lower()  
    counter = 0
    for char in eachWord:
        if char in KB1:
            counter +=1
        if counter == len(eachWord):
            TimesPatternsAppear +=1
print(TimesPatternsAppear)
```

Comment: Is there any way to adapt this to detect them within a string such as 

       "qwertyuiop"

So here it would detect qwe,wer,ert,rty,tyu,yui,uio,iop

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to create a list containing the different possible combinations:

```py
KB1 = ["q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p"]
Example = ("yada yada qwe tYu IoP weR")
TimesPatternsAppear = 0

patterns = []
for i in range(len(KB1)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(KB1)):
        patterns.append("".join(KB1[i:j]))
for word in Example.split():
    if word.lower() in patterns:
        TimesPatternsAppear += 1
print(TimesPatternsAppear)
```

EDIT:

It is possible to adapt this code to detect each match, even partial ones

```py
KB1 = ["q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p"]
Example = ("yada yada qwe tYu IoP weR")
TimesPatternsAppear = 0

patterns = []
for i in range(len(KB1)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(KB1)):
        patterns.append("".join(KB1[i:j]))
for word in Example.split():
    for pattern in patterns:
        if pattern in word.lower():
            TimesPatternsAppear += 1
print(TimesPatternsAppear)
```

Patterns found:

```py
['y', 'y', 'q', 'qw', 'qwe', 'w', 'we', 'e', 't', 'ty', 'tyu', 'y', 'yu', 'u', 'i', 'io', 'o', 'w', 'we', 'wer', 'e', 'er', 'r']
```

EDIT 2:
To only have patterns of length 3:

```py
KB1 = ["q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p"]
Example = ("qwertyuiop")
TimesPatternsAppear = 0

patterns = []
for i in range(len(KB1) - 2):
    patterns.append("".join(KB1[i:i+3]))
for word in Example.split():
    for pattern in patterns:
        if pattern in word.lower():
            TimesPatternsAppear += 1
print(TimesPatternsAppear)
```

Comment: Instead of 8 detections im getting 45 for "qwertyuiop" 

I realise this is really my fault for not explaining myself very well, i mean to find every pattern of 3 such as "qwe" "wer" "ert" etc etc...

Comment: @AP4RK1N5 I updated the code, it should work now

Comment: It has worked and has helped me very much, thank you for being patient and not giving up on me :D